# selenium webdriver.firefox() Error

Tags: python, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to use selenium to start google chrome but i get an error
here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "functional_tests.py", line 5, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

 Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x03D51FD0>> ignored
```

any help with that?

Comment: i read that before I ask .. it's not the same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest `geckodriver` and firefox is installed in default dir.

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH` leads to geckodriver issue, can be solved by providing the path to the geckodriver. Possible reason, geckdriver location is not added to the PATH.

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('path')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

`Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'"` looks like to me your firefox is installed in custom location. Please confirm.